# What is the meaning of "vaults"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have this sentence in an architecture context:

> The concept of the pointed arch allowed architects to change the way they approached vaults in churches and cathedrals.

I'm wondering what the meaning of "vaults" is. I tried googling it and searching in the dictionary but I couldn't find the meaning because as you might know that word has many meanings.

If you could give me a photo of it I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In that case, a [vault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vault_%28architecture%29) is simply, "a roof or ceiling in the form of an arch or a series of arches."

[image: screenshot]